# Nest can't resolve dependencies for MongoDB

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to use MongoDB in my Nest.js project. It seems like I have installed everything correctly, but I keep getting this error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (SessionRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument LogRepository at index [1] is available in the AuthModule context.
```

Here is how it looks like in the code:

```
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AuthModule } from '@auth/auth.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `../../.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_DB_LOGS),
    AuthModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Code of the authentication module:

```
// auth.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { Session } from '@models/session.model';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Log, LogSchema } from '@mongo-schemas/log.schema';

@Module({
  providers: [AuthService],
  exports: [AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  imports: [
    // I also tried different names like: Log, 'Log', Log.name
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Log', schema: LogSchema }]),
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Code of Mongoose schema that I use:

```
// log.schema.ts

import { Schema, Prop, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Log {

  @Prop()
  message: string;
}

export const LogSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Log);
```

Code of the authenticatoin service:

```
import { Log } from '@mongo-schemas/log.schema';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Session) private readonly sessionRepository: typeof Session,
    @InjectModel(Log) private readonly logsRepository: Model<Log>
  ) {}
...
```

Thanks in advance!

PS. Also see, it says `LogRepository`, but I have `LogsRepository`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. The thing is that I am using `@nestjs/sequelize` and `@nestjs/mongoose`in my project, and in the same service I was trying to inject this both sequelize and mongoose models, but the issue is that I was trying to do this by using `@InjectModel` decorator from `@nestjs/sequelize`

```
@InjectModel(Session) private readonly sessionRepository: typeof Session,
@InjectModel(Log) private readonly logsRepository: Model<Log>
```

So, I have imported both decorators, but have changed the name:

```
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { InjectModel as InjectModelMongo } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
```

And now everything works perfectly fine:

```
@InjectModel(Session) private readonly sessionRepository: typeof Session,
@InjectModelMongo(InformationLog.name) private readonly logger: Model<InformationLog>
```